# Arduino Uno Stuck at uploading

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

I wrote a basic blink code and tried to run it on the auduino IDE. Compilation was sucessfull but the code stucks at uploaing. I turned on the verbose output while uploading and this is what I have found..

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is 
"/Users/_stelk/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/_stelk/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, 
skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem101
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
```

I don't exactly understand what to do. Can somebody please help. Board is Arduino Uno but I don't think there is any problem with the hardware. Even when I disconnect the board..the same think happens without giving me an error. Everything was fine last night. When I launch the IDE now, it automatically selects the Uno board and when I hit upload, it compiles sucessfully and stucks at uploading. Should it not give an error like "No board found"? This same behaviour happens even when I connect the board and upload again.

Comment: try to remove `"/Users/_stelk/.avrduderc"`

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Which version of Arduino IDE? That may be relevant to answer this question. Also, the output you posted is just the output of avrdude _before_ trying to open the usb-serial device for programming. Is there really no other option in the preferences that turns on verbose error logging?

Comment: [Found this here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/failed-upload-ide-2-0/1018972): "Occasionally, the [Arduino IDE] 2.0 will upload. This typically happens after closing and reopening the app and using the tools menu to select the port and board instead of the automatic drop down menu. Currently, the port options list old ports that are now not connected. Plugging in to a new port does not updated the port list.", also "make sure the Serial Monitor is closed" -- Looks like there are still a lot of bugs in Arduino IDE 2.0. Which IDE version do you use?

Comment: By "UNO" you refer to an [ATMega328P based UNO](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-uno-rev3) and not to an [UNO WiFi](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-uno-wifi-rev2) or any other board with "UNO" in the name, right?

Comment: Are you using the correct COM port?  On a PC the COM port number can sometimes change when the PC starts or wakes up.  Also do you mean you wrote the blink program by hand or you used the blink program from the examples?  (Is it possible there is a mistake in your code)